# Image slideDown, slideUp using jQuery not working

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have three images in a div. Images in div has absolute position one behind other.I want them to side down one by one. Img1 will slide down first and then slideUp. After that Img2 will slide down and up and so on. I gave some delay for img2 and imd3 as a waiting time.  I can see only img3 sliding down and up. What is wrong am I doing ? Is there better way to do this for multiple images?  If I give different position foe images then all images sliding up and down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img1").slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img2").delay(1500).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img3").delay(3000).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#showPic {
  position: relative;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 100px;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 100px;
}

#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Have a glance !</h1>
<div id="showPic">
  <img id="img1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447752875215-b2761acb3c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" height="500px" width="500px">
  <img id="img2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441974231531-c6227db76b6e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" height="500px" width="500px">
  <img id="img3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474524955719-b9f87c50ce47?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" height="500px" width="500px">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML and images ?

Comment: <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#img1").slideUp(500).delay(500).slideDown(500);
          $("#img2").delay(1500).slideUp(500).delay(500).slideDown(500);
          $("#img3").delay(3000).slideUp(500).delay(500).slideDown(500);      
        });
    </script>

Comment: <div id="showPic">
        <img id="img1"  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447752875215-b2761acb3c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" height="500px" width="500px">
      <img id="img2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441974231531-c6227db76b6e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" height="500px" width="500px">
<img id="img3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474524955719-b9f87c50ce47?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" height="500px" width="500px"></div>

Comment: And please post code in your question with EDIT, not in comments. Also use snippet to create [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add initial `display: none;` on your images in order for them to be able `slideDown`, and all other effects like fade in, show etc (same as animate opacity to 1, you need to have initial opacity 0, same goes with visibility).

And as they are all stacked on top of each other your last one just shown itself on top of others..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img1").slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img2").delay(1500).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img3").delay(3000).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
#showPic {
  position: relative;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="img1" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.cnbcfm.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fimage%2F106256503-1574274174070yoda.jpg%3Fv%3D1574274186&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
<img id="img2" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpmcvariety.files.wordpress.com%2F2019%2F12%2Fbaby-yoda-plush-toy-mattel-the-mandalorian.png%3Fw%3D1000%26h%3D563%26crop%3D1&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
<img id="img3" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kinja-img.com%2Fgawker-media%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Ft_original%2Foicrsr3wwqi6u3buvvxx.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to set unique class to your container and to your slides make a use each function to loop for each images (slide) in your slider container.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sliderDelay = 2500; // delay between each slides exept the first one
  var sliderEffectIn = "slideDown"; // effect in : slideDown, fadeIn, show
  var sliderEffectOut = "slideUp"; // effect out : slideUp, fadeOut, hide
  var sliderEffectDuration = 500; // duration of effect
  
  // we loop on each slides in slider container
  $('.slider .slide').each(function(index, element) {
    // if first slide = no delay
    if (index == 0) {
      $(element)[sliderEffectIn](sliderEffectDuration, function() {
       $(this).delay(sliderEffectDuration)[sliderEffectOut](sliderEffectDuration);
      });
    } else {
      $(element).delay(sliderDelay * index)[sliderEffectIn](sliderEffectDuration, function() {
         $(this).delay(sliderEffectDuration)[sliderEffectOut](sliderEffectDuration);
      }); 
    }   
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <img class="slide" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.cnbcfm.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fimage%2F106256503-1574274174070yoda.jpg%3Fv%3D1574274186&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
  <img class="slide" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpmcvariety.files.wordpress.com%2F2019%2F12%2Fbaby-yoda-plush-toy-mattel-the-mandalorian.png%3Fw%3D1000%26h%3D563%26crop%3D1&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
  <img class="slide" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kinja-img.com%2Fgawker-media%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Ft_original%2Foicrsr3wwqi6u3buvvxx.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img1").slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img2").delay(1500).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
  $("#img3").delay(3000).slideDown(500).delay(500).slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
#showPic {
  position: relative;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="img1" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.cnbcfm.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fimage%2F106256503-1574274174070yoda.jpg%3Fv%3D1574274186&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
<img id="img2" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpmcvariety.files.wordpress.com%2F2019%2F12%2Fbaby-yoda-plush-toy-mattel-the-mandalorian.png%3Fw%3D1000%26h%3D563%26crop%3D1&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
<img id="img3" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kinja-img.com%2Fgawker-media%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Ft_original%2Foicrsr3wwqi6u3buvvxx.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="Trulli" width="250" height="150">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).